# Priority Queue Sorting String

Tags: java, sorting, priority-queue

I need to use a PriorityQueue to sort Person objects.

The Person class:

```
    public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName){
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {return firstName;}

    public String getLastName() {return lastName;}

    public String toString(){
       return "Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName + "\n";
    }

    public int compareTo(Person p){
       String pname1 = firstName + lastName;
       String pname2 = p.firstName + p.lastName;
       return pname1.compareTo(pname2);
    }
```

The main code:

```
    import java.util.PriorityQueue;

    public class priorityQ{
        public static void main(String[] args){
           PriorityQueue<Person> pers = new PriorityQueue<Person>();
           pers.add(new Person("Sam", "Smith"));
           pers.add(new Person("Charlie", "Black"));
           pers.add(new Person("Betty", "Brown"));
           pers.add(new Person("Jessica", "Stewart"));
           pers.add(new Person("John", "Friday"));
           pers.add(new Person("Frank", "Folcy"));
           System.out.print(pers);      
       }   
    }
```

I need to:

1. Print without sort (already done in main)
2. Sort by last name
3. Sort by first name, then last name

I must not change any code in the Person class.

I created new class:

```
    import java.util.Comparator;
    public class LastNameComparator implements Comparator<Person>{
       public int compareTo(Person a, Person b){
         Person p1 = (Person)a;
         Person p2 = (Person)b;
         if(p1.getLastName().equals(p2.getLastName()))
         {
            return p1.getFirstName().compareTo(p2.getFirstName());
         }
         return p1.getLastName().compareTo(p2.getLastName());
       }
    }
```

It has a compile error:

```
LastNameComparator.java:2: error: LastNameComparator is not abstract and does not override abstract method compare(Person,Person) in Comparator
```

Comment: do you need to use `PriorityQueue` also?

Comment: do what the error message tells you: `does not override compare(Person, Person)` - you named it compareTo

Comment: the @Override Annotation would tell you the error, because compareTo does not override anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to remove `comparable interface` from the `person class` and its all implementations: 
try to do like this:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
    public class LastNameComparator implements Comparator<Person>{    
    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {

        return o1.lastname.compareTo(o2.lastname);
    }
    }
```

And in `main method` do the following for sort by Last Name:

```
Collections.sort(pers,new LastNameComparator());
    Iterator<Person> it = pers.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next());
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
Please remove

```
implements Comparable<Person>
```

and

```
 public int compareTo(Person p){
       String pname1 = firstName + lastName;
       String pname2 = p.firstName + p.lastName;
       return pname1.compareTo(pname2);
    }
```

from Person class, since you are not aloud to do any changes in it.

Second:
Comparator Class have only compare(T ob1, T2 ob2) method, there are no  public int compareTo(Person a, Person b).
So please create compare(T ob1, T2 ob2) and put @Override annotation on top of it to be sure you did everything right.

So after all in you Comparator class have to be

```
@Override
public int compare(Person a, Person b){
//..your code
}
```

Rest of code seems fine, from quick look...